Why did my Oracle DBMS install fail?
I'm trying to install Oracle DBMS. The actual install was successful, but then I received this error:

Enterprise manager configuration failed due to the following
error -
Error starting Database Control
Refer to the log file at C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_4\cfgtoollogs\dbca\draft1\emConfig.log for more details. You can retry configuring this database with Enterprise
Manager later by manually running C:\oracle\product\10.2.20\db_4\bin\emca script.


Trying to install it in the VM.
The error says that the exception happened during  clone creation.
Is there a way to fix it? Maybe everything is already installed?

Update: As requested here is the last couple of lines from the install log:
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:04:40 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:04:51 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:05:01 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:05:11 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:05:22 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:05:34 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:05:44 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:05:54 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:06:05 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:06:16 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:06:26 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:06:36 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:06:46 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:06:56 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:07:06 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:07:16 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:07:26 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:07:36 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:07:46 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:07:56 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:08:06 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:08:16 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.PlatformInterface serviceCommand
CONFIG: Waiting for service 'OracleDBConsoledraft1' to fully start
Dec 2, 2024 7:08:26 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform
SEVERE: Error starting Database Control
Refer to the log file at C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_4\cfgtoollogs\dbca\draft1\emConfig.log for more details.
Dec 2, 2024 7:08:26 AM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform
CONFIG: Stack Trace: 
oracle.sysman.emcp.exception.EMConfigException: Error starting Database Control
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMDBPostConfig.performConfiguration(EMDBPostConfig.java:569)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMDBPostConfig.invoke(EMDBPostConfig.java:181)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMDBPostConfig.invoke(EMDBPostConfig.java:150)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig.perform(EMConfig.java:155)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.em.EMConfiguration.run(EMConfiguration.java:430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)

Now to answer the question in the second post - the VM is running Windows 10 and it does have static IP address. And no, I didn't try to run anything yet. I'm still at that screenshot.

Does the server have a static IP address, and have you ran set oracle_sid=orcl, emca -repos recreate, and emca start dbconsole?

What is the version of java, have you try with installing 1.8?

@RomeoNinov, I didn’t explicitly install Java. The installer was using the one that is built-in.

@Igor, install 1.8.last, set JAVA_HOME, PATH and start the procedure again.

@Igor - So can you manually install the appropriate version of Java? A service is failing to start.

I presume I need Java Run-Time and not JDK, right?

@Ramhound, I installed latest Java 1.8 and the install went thru fine. Thx a lot.

@Igor - Sounds like you should submit a detailed answer. Document everything.
